# How to edit yaml file for custom classes in yolov5 model?

Tags: python, image-processing, yaml, yolo, yolov5

I am training a yolov5 model for a custom dataset. I have only one class. I have changed the .yaml file as my data as follows.

```
train: /content/yolov5/DataSet/ForYolov5/images/train  # train images (relative to 'path') 128 images
val: /content/yolov5/DataSet/ForYolov5/images/test  # val images (relative to 'path') 128 images
test:  # test images (optional)

# Classes
names:
  0: vehicle
```

But the name vehicle is not displaying on the detections. only '0' is displayed. I tried with the following format too. But it throws out errors.

```
#Classes
nc:1
names:['vehicle']
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After creating your custom dataset (I suppose you have 2 folder train and valid), you should too customize your YAML file using the code below:

```
%cat data.yaml
# define number of classes based on YAML
# data.yaml contains the information about number of classes and their labels required for this project
import yaml
with open("data.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    num_classes = str(yaml.safe_load(stream)['nc'])
    #customize iPython writefile so we can write variables
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_cell_magic

@register_line_cell_magic
def writetemplate(line, cell):
    with open(line, 'w') as f:
        f.write(cell.format(**globals()))

%%writetemplate /content/dataset/data.yaml

train: /content/dataset/train/images/
val:  /content/dataset/valid/images/

nc: 1 #define number of class = 1
names: ['vehicule'] #class label
```

Then you have to check that the class is changed in the architecture file:

```
%cat /content/yolov5/models/yolov5n.yaml
%%writetemplate /content/yolov5/models/yolov5n.yaml

# Parameters
nc: 1 # number of classes
```